# How do I find a file in a directory, from a CSV list, then move that file to another folder? Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, shutil

I have a csv file with Row 1 being the headers, column 1(A) is the file name I am looking for e.g. i_suck_at_python.xlsx and column 2(B) is the folder name I want to move it to e.g. Lex sucks at Python.

I have done similar on Openpyxl, except I only managed to do it on a single row. 
Here is my code below. Your help is appreciated.

Also, I had a huge amount of problems with encoding, this line in particular:

```
with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
```

The file was originally an xlsx, but then I had to save it as a csv. the 'r' was 'rb' before, then I read I had to change it and also the encoding specifics, but to no avail.

Anyway, here is the code for the actual problem:

```
import csv
import os
import shutil

def main():

    csv_file = "G:\Key Accounts\Ebills\Lex Bot Test\Test 2\EB Mapping.csv"
    existing_path_prefix = "G:\Key Accounts\Ebills\Lex Bot Test\Test 2\PDFs"
    new_path_prefix = "G:\Key Accounts\Ebills\Lex Bot Test\Test 2\PDFs"

    with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
      reader = csv.reader(f)
      for row in reader:
        file_name = row[0]
        folder_name = row[1]
        newFolderPath = os.path.join("G:\Key Accounts\Ebills\Lex Bot 
        Test\Test 2\PDFs", folder_name)
        existingFilePath = os.path.join("G:\Key Accounts\Ebills\Lex Bot 
        Test\Test 2\PDFs", file_name)

        if file_name in existing_path_prefix:
          print ("File Exists in: {}".format (existing_path_prefix))
          shutil.move(existingFilePath, newFolderPath)
          print ("File successfully moved")
          break
        else:
          print ("There has been a problem")
main ()
```

The code runs, but it is just going straight to my else statement, meaning it isn't picking up the files in the folder. Thanks again.

Thought I should mention, I'm happy if someone were to suggest going about this completely differently, e.g. Pandas, numpy, openpyxl, xlrd etc

Edit: So, I want to search for the file in A2, and when it is found move it to the folder in B2, then loop to the next line until the end of the file. The folder(s) already exists in the same directory as the .xlsx file. Sample lines from CSV file:

```
File Name                    Folder Name
i_suck_at_python.xlsx        Lex sucks at Python
python_test.xlsx             Python Test
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to ensure the indenting is absolutely correct for the code you have given. e.g. it should be indented inside the function.

Comment: Apologies, added now. Thanks for heads up.

Comment: The indentation is wrong. `else` should have the same indentation as `if`. Also .. did you try to debug the code using the debugger?

Comment: And I guess this whole if-else should be inside the for loop so. Also the string is not interpretable. The program I see here should not even start to run.

Comment: Hi @StefanFalk. I have fixed the indent again (apologies, making a bit of a mess of this question here - let's blame it on me being new). The if-else is inside the loop. I have used the debugger, but I don't really know what I'm looking for. In hindsight, I shouldn't have posted without doing further research. Sorry for time wasting!

Comment: Can you add a few sample lines from your CSV file? It is not clear whether you are trying to copy individual files or whole folders.

Comment: @MartinEvans Hi Martin, thanks for coming back to me. I have added the example of what the CSV file looks like. I have been reading about (including some answer you have gave on other questions) and wondering if I'm best using xlrd or openpyxl? The file originally is xlsx, and I know csv struggles with that.

Comment: It is usually easier to work with a CSV but both `xlrd` or `openpyxl` are good. I often use `xlrd` if only reading is needed, and `openpyxl` if read and write are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, I am assuming you are trying to do the following:

From:

```
Test 2
└── PDFs
    ├── i_suck_at_python.xlsx
    └── python_test.xlsx
```

To:

```
Test 2
└── PDFs
    ├── Lex sucks at Python
    │   └── i_suck_at_python.xlsx
    └── Python Test
        └── python_test.xlsx
```

Firstly, you need to add an `r` prefix to your path strings. This stops Python trying to escape any backslashes. Alternatively you could use forward slashes instead.

When using a `csv.reader()` the file should be opened with the `newline=''` parameter in Python 3.x, previously in Python 2.x it needed `rb`.

Using `in` will not test if your file is present in a given folder, instead it just check if the string on the left can be found in the string on the right. To actually test if a file exists, you could use [`os.path.exists()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists), but if it is just to ensure that you can copy it, then it is better to use exception handling around the move, i.e. if it can't find the file it will generate the exception.

```
import csv
import os
import shutil

def main():
    csv_file = r"G:\Key Accounts\Ebills\Lex Bot Test\Test 2\EB Mapping.csv"
    from_folder = r"G:\Key Accounts\Ebills\Lex Bot Test\Test 2\PDFs"
    to_folder = r"G:\Key Accounts\Ebills\Lex Bot Test\Test 2\PDFs"

    with open(csv_file, 'r', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)

        for row in reader:
            file_name = row[0]
            folder_name = row[1]

            from_filename = os.path.join(from_folder, file_name)
            to_filename = os.path.join(to_folder, folder_name, file_name)

            try:
                shutil.move(from_filename, to_filename)
                print("Moved - '{}' -> '{}'".format(from_filename, to_filename))
            except shutil.Error as e:
                print("Failed - '{}' -> '{}'".format(from_filename, to_filename))

main()
```

Comment: This worked very well, thank you Martin. All I had to change was the (existing_file_path, new_folder_path) to my variables and it worked.